# Boost.Signals2 destruction safety

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost-signals2

I have a Boost.Signals2 signal on object 1, and I connect to it on object 2.
If object 2 is destructed the signal will not disconnect which can lead to bad things when its signaled.
To resolve this I keep a `scoped_connection` on object 2. The problem now is what if object 1 destructs with the signal and then object 2 destructs.
Will it cause problems? Is there any better way to resolve the general issue? (have a connection from object 1 -> object 2 that will disconnect when on of them destructs).

A code that demonstrates the issue:

```
auto sig = new signal<void ()>();
auto conn = new scoped_connection(sig.connect(&some_function));
delete sig;
delete conn;
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.connection-management

Especially the part:

> "However, with Boost.Signals2 one may track any object which is
>   managed by a shared_ptr, by using slot::track. A slot will
>   automatically disconnect when any of its tracked objects expire. In
>   addition, Boost.Signals2 will ensure that no tracked object expires
>   while the slot it is associated with is in mid-execution. It does so
>   by creating temporary shared_ptr copies of the slot's tracked objects
>   before executing it. "

Does this solve your issue?